# Duplicate several tables in bigquery project at once

Tags: google-bigquery

In our BQ export schema, we have one table for each day as per the screenshot below.

I want to copy the tables before a certain date (2021-feb-07). I know how to copy one day at a time via the UI, but is there not a way to use the cloud console to write a code for copying the selected date range, all at once? Or maybe an sql command directly from a query window?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should transform your sharding tables into a partitioned table. So you can handled your tables with just a single query. As mention in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard), partitioned tables perform better.

To make the conversion, you can just execute the following commands in the console.

```
bq partition \
--time_partitioning_type=DAY \
--time_partitioning_expiration 259200 \
mydataset.sourcetable_ \
mydataset.mytable_partitioned
```

This will make your sharded tables `sourcetable_(xxx)` into a single partitioned table `mytable_partitioned` which can be query with just a single query trough your entire set of data entries.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `myprojectid.mydataset.mytable_partitioned`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2022-01-03')
```

For more details about the conversion commands you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#convert-date-sharded-tables). Also, I recommend to check the links about [querying partionated tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables) and [partiotioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) for more details.

Comment: Hey @WytrzymałyWiktor. Yes, I made a script that made copies, since making partition is not an option in our use-case.